How do I limit the disk space a Docker container can use?
I created a container for Cassandra using the command "docker run -p 9042:9042 --rm --name cassandra -d cassandra:4.0.7" and after it starts the disk usage on my windows machine goes to 100% usage
I can't find anywhere how to limit the writes if Cassandra

I used this dicker compose final to limit cassandra:
 version: '3.7'
services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:latest
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          blkio_config:
            weight: 500
            weight_device:
              - path: /dev/sda
                weight: 500
            throttle_read_bps_device:
              - path: /dev/sda
                rate: '10mb'
            throttle_write_bps_device:
              - path: /dev/sda
                rate: '10mb'
    volumes:
      - cassandra-data:/var/lib/cassandra
volumes:
  cassandra-data:


You can limit the available disk space for containers depending on the filesystem you're using. For example, you can set a quota with the pquota option on XFS.
Note that doing so means that whatever application you're running in the container can impact its operation when it runs out of disk space. For Cassandra, the instance will shutdown immediately with the default disk_failure_policy: stop configuration.
For more info, see Setting driver options per container. Cheers!
